# Creating a map from property names to types with that property

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I've just spent about 20 minutes trying to work out if there's a neat/LINQy way to populate this dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<Type>> _propertyMap;
```

It's intended to be a dictionary that maps the names of public properties to types that have such a property, from a limited list of types.

I'm sure there must be a clever way to take a list of types, expand that out into pairs of `{Type, PropertyInfo}` and from there construct this dictionary, but I just can't fathom it out.

Here's the current way that I populate this dictionary. (`_types` is a `List<Type>`):

```
_propertyMap = new Dictionary<string, List<Type>>();
foreach (var t in _types)
{
    foreach (var p in t.GetProperties(
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if (_propertyMap.ContainsKey(p.Name))
        {
            _propertyMap[p.Name].Add(t);
        }
        else
        {
            _propertyMap[p.Name] = new List<Type> {t};
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ query:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

_propertyMap = _types.SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties(flags))
                     .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
                     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                                   g => g.Select(p => p.DeclaringType).ToList());
```

Side note - you can use `ILookup<string, Type>` instead of `Dictionary<string, List<Type>>` then query will look this way:

```
_propertyMap = _types.SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties(flags))
                     .ToLookup(p => p.Name, p => p.DeclaringType);
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, and you are right - deleted it unintentionally when was formatting code to fit width of code block

Comment: No need to use additional `GroupBy`. Just `types.SelectMany(x => x.GetProperties(flags)).ToLookup(x => x.Name, x => x.DeclaringType)`

Answer (score 0):

I was mostly happy with [Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22865440/15498) and will continue to leave that as accepted.

However, in my particular case, I later ran into trouble when I had two types where one inherited from the other. In that case, `DeclaringType` returns the base class for both the base and derived classes.

So my tweak to it, which is a bit closer to what I originally speculated as an approach, was:

```
types.SelectMany(t => t
         .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
         .Select(p=>new{t,p}))
.GroupBy(p => p.p.Name)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(p => p.t).ToList());
```